# Is there any fucntion to create or keep black pixels inside canny edge detected areas?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm about to learning opencv's canny edge detection module for my work.i need to know if there is any function to create or keep black pixels inside canny edge detected areas?

**the code i did used**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
def auto_canny(image, sigma=0.33):
    v = np.median(image)
    lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - sigma) * v))
    upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + sigma) * v))
    edged = cv2.Canny(image, lower, upper)
    cv2.imwrite("01edged.jpg",edged)
    bt = cv2.bitwise_not(edged)
    cv2.imwrite("0bt.jpg", bt)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cv2.drawContours(bt, contours, 0, (0, 0, 0), 1)  # ---set the last parameter to -1
    cv2.imwrite("001.jpg", bt)
```

**from sample image i want to keep or create the black pixel inside text's edge areas.**

[image]

**input image**

[image]

Comment: Post the input image. How about using filled contours?

Comment: @fmw42, I did uploaded the input image,as you can see the difference of input and canny processed output images.

Comment: The very idea of `canny` is to detect the edges, maybe you should describe why you are using `canny` at all. What you are describing so far means you want to keep your input image the way it is.

Comment: @roadrunner66 because i want to recognize the words inside the some colored regions or shapes.

Comment: kk, can you update your images to reflect that, I'm still not sure I get it

Comment: You can recognize words without edge detection. Just threshold the image, use morphology to isolate words, then get the bounding boxes of the contours. Feed that to tesseract.